# Can web connections from a virtual machine guest using NAT attract attacks from the Web to the host?

Tags: attacks, virtualization

The hosts OS might be Windows 7 and its firewall activated and the visualization is done by Virtual Box , but I think these details are less important.

This question might be related in some way to [this which focuses on bridged mode](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3719/is-there-a-way-to-identify-the-host-of-a-malicious-vm-from-across-the-network), but my focus here is on using **NAT**.

**Edit:**

Can malicious sites one visits from inside the VM, identify the host, scan its ports etc.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  I have no idea what word(s) **attrac** and **attacts** are exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes". If a guest is infected, it could certainly attempt a vulnerability scan of other devices on your network, including the host OS. This is assuming you haven't done something like placing the guest OS's network adaptor into a different VLAN or something similar. I doubt you have. Another way to avoid this would be to leave the host OS with an IP stack that isn't configured, thus mmaking it unable to communicate with the rest of the network. This also assumes it doesn't grab an address via DHCP. This is certainly an option if you don't plan to use the host OS for anything other than running guest VMs. But if you use the host OS for anything network related, then this may not be an option.

Comment: Putting something in a VLAN? I think you mean isolated network. A VLAN can be layer 3 and route to another network. Which would not protect much.

Comment: A VLAN without an IP address assigned to the VLAN interface is an isolated network. A VLAN is a Layer 2 feature.

Comment: My point being, having a "VLAN" does not implicitly mean a network is isolated as it is very common to route between VLANs. You should clarify this in your answer.